# Wordpress: Links to External URLs Adds site URL as a Prefix

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having trouble figuring out why my site is adding a url to external links. I am creating social icons for the footer and notice this happening. I am just placing the code into a text widget. You can [view my site](https://www.healncure.com/) and scroll to the footer to see the issue.

Below is my HTML coding

```
<a class="social" href=”https://www.facebook.com/healncure” target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.healncure.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/facebook-bw.jpg" /><img alt="" src="http://www.healncure.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/facebook-hover.jpg" /></a>
```

If you want to see the [code](http://codepen.io/CookieFresh89/pen/KgluE) for the social icons to check the coding. I tried searching to see if anyone else is having this problem and only found one other person but they just had incomplete code.

This all started happening after I got my site ssl certified. I am not sure if this has anything to do with it. Maybe if some sort of setting was changed. If it is trying to redirect the url.

I have already tried deactivating all the plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the wrong double quotes.

Change href=”https://www.facebook.com/healncure” to href="https://www.facebook.com/healncure"